# Describe the triangle whose angles will be in the equivalence class of (60, 60, 60).

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

The relation here is the largest angle in common. At a first glance I think that it should be a equilateral triangle but now I think it should be as (60, 55,65) what do you guys think can we describe this tringle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we go,
The triangles are equilateral because the largest angle is 60, which indicates that the sum of other two angles must be 120, for this condition to be satisfy these two angles must be equal and would measure 60 degree.
First I thought that (60, 65,55) should be answer but than the largest angle will be 65.
Sorry for this nonsense thinking!

Comment: There are no stupid questions. Please describe what you thought was wrong and how you managed to solve the problem and you will possibly help someone else with that knowledge :)

Comment: Okay, I will try, but it's kinda funny for others.

Comment: Thanks man, I explained it.

Comment: Great :) Noticing the mistake yourself lead to you a deeper understanding then just getting it right in the first place :)